# Custom List: How to populate multiple columns of type 'Person or Group'?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, person

[image]

I have three columns of type 'Person or Group' as above. I want all the columns to be populated at once when user input 'FirstName LastName' column.

[image]

I created a Workflow as above, but it only populated after user save and refresh the list.

I wonder if I could set up a specific timing (when user input the first column) to start the Workflow or any other way to populate all the other columns at once other than using this Workflow.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to just hide the email and role fields using content types and have the workflow set those to match upon submit.  That seems like the easiest, most straight forward approach.  If that doesn't meet your needs you could do this via javascript/jQuery.  I've done similar using the below

```
$(document).on("change, keypress", "input[title='FieldName']", FunctionToRun);
```

FieldName = FirstName LastName

FunctionToRun = the name of the function that sets the email and role fields:

```
$("input[title='Email']").val($("input[title='FirstName LastName']").val())
```

Comment: Thank you:) Your first approach seems practical for my environment.